# Reference to function return value

Tags: c++, reference, rvalue-reference

Take this example:

```
#include <string> 

std::string Foo() {
  return "something";
}

std::string Bar() {
  std::string str = "something";
  return str;
}
```

I don't want to copy the return value, what is better between these two options? And why?

```
 int main() {
   const std::string& a = Foo();
   std::string&& b = Foo(); 
   // ... 
 }
```

If I use Bar function now (instead of Foo), are there some difference between main() written above?

```
 int main() {
   const std::string& a = Bar();
   std::string&& b = Bar(); 
   // ... 
 }
```

Comment: _"I don't want to copy the return value, what is better between these two options?"_ Just let the compiler do this. You may read up about _copy elision_.

Comment: With a modern compiler, you can write `std::string a = Foo();` or `std::string b = Bar();` and the return value will be created in-place.

Comment: `main` is not a global `int` variable that can be initialized with source code ;-)

Comment: edited to correct 'main' to 'main()'. 
Thanks everyone for answer.

Comment: if you consider such micro optimizations you should look at what the compiler produces as output. This is a great tool to do so: https://godbolt.org/ . However, you shouldnt consider it unless you measured and found that it actually has an impact on performance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> what is better between these two options?

Neither. This is an exercise in premature optimization. You are trying to do the compilers job for it. Return value optimization and copy elision is practically law now. And move-semantics (applicable for a type like `std::string`) already provide truly efficient fallbacks.

So let the compiler do its thing, and prefer value semantics:

```
auto c = Foo();
auto d = Bar();
```

As for `Bar` vs `Foo`. Use whichever you prefer. `Bar` in particular is RVO friendly. So both will very likely end up being the same.

Comment: Funny that you consider `Bar` to be more friendly. I'd say that `Foo` is friendlier, because of guaranteed copy elision, which doesn't happen for `Bar`. Is there any reason why that I'm not aware of?

Comment: @Rakete1111 - I don't consider it more friendly. My use of "in particular" was to single it out. This NRVO is covered by [copy.elision] in C++17.

Comment: Wait, so NRVO is also part of guaranteed copy elision?

Comment: @Rakete1111 - For constexpr functions only. For others it's "highly recommended"